# Get Entities from Azure table storage (limit 1)

Tags: azure, logic

I was trying to get entities from table storage using connector in Logic APPS.
filter query is as follows.

```
chequeNo eq '@{variables('chequeNo')}'
```

This return all the entries but I want to return only 1.

Not able to find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"queries": {
                        "$filter": "chequeNo eq '@{variables('chequeNo')}'",
                        "$top": "1"
                    }
```

Added $top: "1"

Comment: seems like this one is hidden chit code :) 
Is there anything similar for set order by (sorting)??