# Fetch top n rows from azure table

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage

I have a logic app in which  I need to fetch top 100 records from azure table storage  for a given condition.  Is is possible in logic app  Get Entities connector to fetch only 100 records per request ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is is possible in logic app Get Entities connector to fetch only 100 records per request ?

For logic app, it does not support `top` query, it only support `filter` and `select` query.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuretables/#get-entities).

Comment: As of `20 July 2021`, you can manually add the `$top` into `queries` using code editor of logic app. Just tried and it works.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61630349/get-entities-from-azure-table-storage-limit-1