# Sorting azure table storage entities in azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage

I'm experimenting with Logic Apps and I have the following question:

There are log entries stored in an "LogEntries" table in Azure Table Storage.
Is it possible to use a Logic App to return the 10 most recent "LogEntries" records based on the Timestamp of the record?

I found that you can turn on pagination, so I can limit the number of records it returns, but I'm not sure how to sort the records.

If so, can someone tell me which steps to use?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Azure logic app` may not support sorting operations, you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. So that basically makes a logic a app unsuitable in this case.
Other option would be to store the records in Cosmos DB or something  of course...

Comment: As of now, we can have top 10 records.. see this one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61634360/1659563 not sure about sorting

Comment: You can get `top` 100 records and do sorting in logic app by Inline Javascript..